# Can someone explain the discrepancy in `cgroups` memory usage that I'm seeing here?

Tags: linux, cgroups

I am on Ubuntu 22 by the way. EDIT: With kernel 5.19.0-50-generic (was having some AMD problems on 6 so I downgraded).

I am trying to write a benchmarker using Linux cgroups, but I'm running into a discrepancy between what I *think* I should see and what I *actually* see. As an example, I have the following C++ program:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    const int MEM_AMT = 1024 * 1024;
    float* my_mem = new float[MEM_AMT];
    int mem_index = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < __INT_MAX__; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < __INT_MAX__; i++)
        {
            my_mem[mem_index] = static_cast<float>(i) * sinf(i * 32) + cosf(i * 32);
            mem_index++;
            if (mem_index == MEM_AMT)
                mem_index = 0;
        }
    }

    delete my_mem;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm basically just crunching a bunch of numbers and storing them in an array.

When I inspect the memory usage using `psutil`, I get something like this:

```
pmem(rss=6721536, vms=10395648, shared=2560000, text=4096, lib=0, data=4599808, dirty=0)
```

When I inspect the memory usage using `top`, I get something like this:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                    
  43240 matthew   20   0   10152   6564   2500 R 100.0   0.0   6:30.62 a.out
```

However, when I add the process to a cgroup and `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/my_group/memory.current`, **I see that 0 is written in there**!

My question for you all is: Why does `memory.current` contain zero?

DISCLAIMER: I have already confirmed that the process ID is in the cgroup.

**EDIT**:

I have also confirmed the same behavior on a box running kernel 6.4.12-060412-generic

**UPDATE**:

This was a tricky one, but hopefully this will clear up the confusion for anyone else with this problem. By default `systemd` creates a number of slices. You can even set up your slices by yourself if you want.

One such slice is the `user.slice`, which you can find at`/sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice`. Since I launched my process from a gnome-terminal session, I found the pid of my C++ process under `user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-org.gnome.Terminal.slice/vte-spawn-<SOME_UUID>.scope/cgroup.procs`. Lo-and-behold, this directory had a `memory.current` file containing the proper memory information

In fact, any process that you spawn (in Ubuntu at least) seems to end up in a directory. e.g. here is where my PID for emacs ends up: `user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/snap.emacs.emacs-5f254e0c-647b-41a4-b31b-0ff257acdd90.scope`.

So what did we learn? Your process *can* exist in two different cgroup hierarchies at the same time, but the process cannot *add to the statistics of two different hierarchies*.

If you are trying to use `cgroups` as a benchmarking platform like me, beware of this intricacy!