# VmRss for a process is growing linearly and not stabilizing. Can it be a memory leak?

Tags: linux, memory-management, memory-leaks, swap

So I have a alma OS 64-bit linux based application. My application has various process out of which one of them, let's call it "VoicemailApp" is showing linear increase in VmRss over a period of 30 days. Also the system has been under heavy load at this time but the load is constant, it has not growing.

Can it be a memory leak? Other points to consider :

1. The RAM is not increasing linearly. It is 50% occupied.
2. The swap memory is consumed 100% (can that be indicator of memory leak?)

please provide pointers on how I can be sure that it is a leak or not.

I have analyzed the valgrind report of the process, it didn't seem alarming or containing any major leaks.

Comment: Without a way to reproduce your problem, readers will be guessing to offer an real answer. Please read [mcve] and see if you can post code that interested readers can copy/paste into their own environment to reproduce your problem. Otherwise, this will liely be vote-closed as "too broad". Good luck.

Comment: See a [very recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77113787/620097) with a good [mcve] .

Comment: it is a performance based question. On the basis of performance metric can we conclude anything? If not then what all things can I check in my application?